# Form inputs being disabed during the Ajax request

Tags: forms, ajax

I'm working on a module where I have a *form* inside of a *block*, I'm using `Ajax` to submit the form, but I noticed that the form's inputs are disabled when sending a request with Ajax. Well in my case I want to keep using the form's input (keyup event) and displaying the result for each request.

```
// my current code
$form['combine'] = array(
    '#type'       => 'textfield',
    '#size'       => 255,
    '#maxlength'  => 128,
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => 'Search'),
    '#ajax'     => array(
        'callback'  => 'ajax_filter_callback',
        'effect'    => 'fade',
        'wrapper'   => 'result-content',
        'event'     => 'keyup',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Is there a reason to not use autocomplete functionality for this? I think that it will not disable the input element when using this method. Drupal Examples has this where you can see how they implement this: https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example_autocomplete.inc/7

Comment: @burnsjeremy I don't know, maybe I'll use autocomplete, it's just a big query with many joins, it's a customized filter in fact, I used Views combined filter but it's a bit limited for my case, so I developed my own module, with a form in a block as a filter (the one that gets its inputs disabled), but I'll take the idea of autocomplete into consideration. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality is built-in so you'll need to monkey-patch `Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend` (found in misc/ajax.js).

Copy the entire code, but remove/modify this line:

```
$(this.element).addClass('progress-disabled').attr('disabled', true);
```

So in your module or theme's JS file:

```
Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend = function(xmlhttprequest, options) {
  // Place all code from the original function here, except the line above.
}
```

YMMV, you may unwittingly introduce unexpected behaviour by not waiting for each request to complete.

Comment: Thanks @clive, I know I may run into problems, but I guess it's not that elegant to disable the inputs, maybe wait behind the scene for the request to complete to make a new one, I don't know, I'll think about it, thanks again.